# IP address '172.31.23.211' could not be resolved: Name or service not known

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have the problem connecting EC2 to the Mysql Rds. They are in the same VPC and security group,
which the security group allows access from all IP address, both inbound and outbound. 
The weird thing is I can connect to the database through Mysql Workbench from my laptop, but when I try to access the database through the webpage running on EC2, the page goes blank and the error log shows:
`IP address '172.31.23.211' could not be resolved: Name or service not known`

I don't know what could be wrong, could somebody help me? This is the code for my PHP webpage:

```
   public function __construct() {
        $db = 'mysql:host=lastchance.XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306;dbname=PTPA_DATABASE';
        $user = 'XXXX';
        $password = '(~fPc,BTf$C9KV3X';

        try {
            $this->DB = new PDO ( $db, $user, $password );
            $this->DB->setAttribute ( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        } catch ( PDOException $e ) {
            echo ('Error establishing Connection');
            exit ();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you ssh into your ec2 instance and try to connect?

Comment: Hi Moored, I am sorry for the late reply. I tried to ssh into the ec2. It seemed like It could connect.

Comment: After that, I tried to set up a new application using elastic beanstalk and set up the database when I first initialized the beanstalk instance. I checked the security group and subnet/gateways kind of stuff and it should be ok. But this time when I tried to log in through the front page of my web app: it shows: Error establishing Connection

Comment: It is weird because the web app worked a few month ago when I worked with my classmates. I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: You ever resolve this issue?